# Elasticsearch not opening in cloud URL

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am getting below error while opening elastic cloud URL

```
Error
    at Fetch._callee3$ (https://id.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/bundles/commons.bundle.js:3:232)
    at l (https://id.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:288:970406)
    at Generator._invoke (https://id.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:288:232)
    at Generator.forEach.e.<computed> [as next] (https://id.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/bundles/kbn-ui-shared-deps/kbn-ui-shared-deps.js:288:970763)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (https://id.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/bundles/commons.bundle.js:3:3991504)
    at _next (https://id.eastus2.azure.elastic-cloud.com:9243/bundles/commons.bundle.js:3:3991815)
```

Also after this I am reloading the elastic cloud, getting below error :

```
{"statusCode":503,"error":"Service Unavailable","message":"No shard available
 for [get [.kibana][_doc][space:default]: routing [null]]: 
[no_shard_available_action_exception] No shard available for [get [.kibana][_doc][space:default]: routing [null]]"}
```

Can aanyone please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error message doesn't sound very helpful, but in the second one it's clear that the `.kibana` index is missing. Do you know why that might have happened there? I would generally look at the following options:

1. If you were using Kibana already and need to restore some visualizations or dashboards, do a partial restore from a snapshot.
2. If you are ok to start over, restart Kibana (potentially remove it from your deployment and then add it again). That should generally recreate the `.kibana` index.
3. If none of that works, contact support.